# Matching dependency versions across multiple Python projects

Tags: python, dependencies, dependency-management

I have about 60 repos containing Python packages, currently using `setuptools` in a *setup.py* (run via `pip install`) to manage third-party dependencies. Most of these packages need to be installed on a system at the same time, which means their dependencies all need to be compatible with eachother.

The dependency versions are specified with `==` because I want to lock the dependencies to specific versions, since I've tested the software against those specific versions, and occasionally a new version of a third-party package will introduce a bug.

I'm constantly struggling to keep dependent package versions in sync across all of the repos. For example, if I update *somepackage* from 1.22.1 to 1.22.2 in one project, I have to then go and modify the *setup.py* in a few dozen other repos to match.

My partial solution right now is to use a lot of virtual environments, but this isn't a complete solution because I still have to maintain compatible dependencies across all the packages within a given venv.

Also, I'm really trying to move away from having separate venvs for various reasons, including:

- It's inconvenient to have to be constantly switching venvs.
- The entry point scripts that get installed are in the venv's *bin*, but I'd rather have all applications be installed globally. I can write scripts that switch to the venv then run the application and install those scripts in a global location, but that makes the deployment workflow very clunky.
- If I release an update to one of *my* packages, I have to install the update in every venv, instead of just once globally. This is inconvenient, error-prone, and time consuming.

**My question is:** Is there some way to more conveniently manage third-party dependency versions across multiple repos that share some of the same dependencies? Using the same example, if I update *somepackage* from 1.22.1 to 1.22.2, I'd really like to just change that version number in one place. If it matters, I'd like to support Python back to at least 3.9.

The only possible solution I've been able to come up with is something like:

- Have a package, let's call it *mysetup*, that exports a bunch of constants containing the version numbers of any dependency that any of the repos use.
- Import that package in *setup.py* and use it to construct the `install_requires` argument to `setup`.

But the main problem with that is that *mysetup* then needs to be manually installed first before installing any of the repo packages, which kind of breaks the deployment flow a bit.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 60 repos containing Python packages

I have a few years' experience working with about double that.
Different repos had different policies.
Many of them would rev independently.
Keeping a repo small and focused leads to
fewer deps and thus fewer conflicts.

> dependency versions are specified with `==`

I support that "strict" policy for a shipping product, especially when
the version numbers are copied out of a running test environment.
It tends to be inconveniently restrictive in a development environment.
Admit point-release bugfixes at the very least,
and consider allowing the minor version to be bumped, as well.
Let's describe either of those as a "loose" approach.
And using e.g. `>= 1.2.3` would be a "liberal" one.

> trying to move away from having separate venvs

I am skeptical that you will ever get down to just one.
Changing your deps implies running 60 test suites to approve that change.
Consider embracing N separate venvs, even if N is less than 60.

Minimally you will need to support the last 2 cPython releases,
implying a minimum of 2 separate venvs, an "old" and a "new" one.

In any event, you will certainly need an automated way to

1. push a dep version change into multiple repos,
2. test in each repo, and
3. accept / rollback the change.

You mentioned local package *mysetup*.
I encourage you to use one or more packages like that in a different way.
In *mysetup*'s setup.py have it
depend on specific (`==`) `install_requires` versions.
Then have your other repos depend on `mysetup`,
so the {pip, conda, poet} solvers will transitively pull in many deps.
You could even publish the (very thin!) mysetup package
on pypi if you like.

In practice I believe you'll want more than one such package,
perhaps with one focused on core functionality including `requests`,
another that pulls in {sqlalchemy, mysql, postgres}, and
another that pulls in things like {numpy, polars, pandas}.
Smaller chunks leads to less DLL hell, fewer conflicting requirements.

---

## updating

Every now and again turn all
the strict `==` deps into liberal `>=` ones,
and take advantage of pip's solver.

Verify your tests succeed.

Commit the new version numbers as strict `==` dependencies.
For example
[pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze)
can produce such a list,
which will then be easy to `git diff` against
the previous set of known-working versions.
Updating frequently means small, low-risk changes.
Conversely, waiting months or years between updates
invites all manner of complex incompatible
version constraints to creep in,
which you get to diagnose and deal with.

---

## simultaneous update

If you have a couple dozen deps,
it's pretty important that several times per year
you update *all* of them simultaneously to most recent release,
and test that it works.

I have seen too many repos attempt the following approach:
Add strict `==` dep A, then weeks elapse.
Later add strict dep B, later C and so on.
Notice that C needs another version of A, so upgrade both.
Eventually packages B and Z are years out of date,
and the solver is faced with hopelessly incompatible constraints.
You could try a liberal approach at that point,
risking that many packages have issued major releases
incompatible with your app. Nightmare ensues.

Keep your app reasonably up-to-date w.r.t. its deps.
And *don't* let A, B, ... Z drift months or years
apart from one another's release dates.
They each have their own graph of dependencies.
You want to test against version combos that
the upstream authors also tested against.
Holding back one library to be years before
another library's release means *you* get
to test that unique combination, and diagnose issues.

---

## reports

Consider writing a script that does `sort | uniq` on a bunch of
`requirements.txt` files, producing a single "superset" of requirements.
If pip finds a solution, propagate the result back into strict `==`
requirements in each repo.
If not, then we probably want smaller chunks,
increasing our chances of finding a valid solution.

Also, when your CI/CD pipeline successfully finishes
running an automated test suite, take care to record
the strict version requirements of deps,
in order to bake them into your release process.

Comment: Is there any tool that helps with "*turning all the strict `==` deps into liberal `>=` ones, taking advantage of pip's solver, […] and [getting] the new version numbers as strict 
`==` dependencies.*"?

Comment: @Bergi, honestly I usually ask emacs or vi to do a global search-n-replace which I later revert without committing. And then I might tack on "give me >= _this_ favorite version" of some package I am examining. Either the solver will find a compatible set of versions or it won't. Once it manages to succeed, the well known [pip freeze](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze) can produce a list of strict `==` versions, which we commit to the repo. I tend to use Conda or Poet to accomplish something similar. A "nuke and start from scratch" approach can make it go quicker.